# l versC# multithread issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I cannot get the ui thread to update the ui while the file copy thread is running. My end goal is to have the animation continue to rotate until the large file copy finally completes to let the user know that the program is not frozen. It's a very simple server to server file copy program.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]
[image: Simple Windows Form]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ResetProgress()
        {
            lblStep1.Image = null;
        }

        private void SetupProgress()
        {
            lblStep1.Image = global::animation1.Properties.Resources.animation;
        }

        private void fileCopy()
        {
            File.Copy("large file source", "large file destination", true);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStep1.Image = global::animation1.Properties.Resources.animation;
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetupProgress();
            await Task.Run(() => fileCopy());
            ResetProgress();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // unhandled currently
        }
    }
}
```

*** Original version ***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Thread workItemsProducerThread;
        private Thread workItemsCopyThread;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ResetProgress()
        {
            lblStep1.Image = null;
        }

        private void SetupProgress()
        {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {
            lblStep1.Image = global::animation1.Properties.Resources.animation;
        });
    }

        private void fileCopy()
        {           
            File.Copy("Large file source", "Large file destination", true);

        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        });

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStep1.Image = global::animation1.Properties.Resources.animation;
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        this.workItemsProducerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.SetupProgress));
        this.workItemsProducerThread.IsBackground = true;
        this.workItemsProducerThread.Start();

        this.SetupProgress();

            this.workItemsCopyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.fileCopy));
            this.workItemsCopyThread.IsBackground = true;
            this.workItemsCopyThread.Start();


        while (workItemsCopyThread.IsAlive)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.workItemsProducerThread != null)
            {
                this.workItemsProducerThread.Abort();
                lblStep1.Image = global::animation1.Properties.Resources.animation;
            }
        }

        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fileCopy();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: There is no reason to run SetupProgress on another thread, on the contrary. It's a bad idea.

Comment: Ok, I've tried both of those suggestions and the symptoms are still the same. I've tried running SetupProgress from the main UI and replaced the begininvoke with just invokes, but the behavior is unchanged.

Comment: @Jay that's because the code is too convoluted. You don't need threads, Invoke or Abort. Henk Holterman's answer shows how easy it is to write this using the built-in Task.Run and async/await.

Comment: Panagiotis, would you mind trying my example to see if it works for you?

Comment: `fileCopy` should be `async` method, and moved out from `Task`, you don't need the thread pool here - it's IO method, they are exactly `async` was made for.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t sleep in your click handler. That freezes the UI thread. Just let the clock handler exit. In your file copy thread, when the copy is don’t. Use Invoke(or BeginInvoke) to cause the done messagebox to pop up on the UI thread.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I've made the corrections above and am still experiencing the same symptoms?

Comment: No reason to use Invoke or threads when Task.Run and `async/await` are available

Comment: You need to remove: the while isalive loop and the messagebox from the click handler. (Async is way easier btw)

Answer (score 0):

Try this oldy style

```
private void SetupProgress()
        {

            Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                lblStep1.Image = global::animation1.Properties.Resources.animation;
            });

        }


 private Thread TDoSomeWork()
        {
            var t = new Thread(() => DoSomeWork());
            t.Start();
            return t;
        }


TDoSomeWork();
```